# Adjust the position of the iOS map annotation title

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mkannotation

The default position of the map annotation title is usually fine most of the time. But when the current user position blue dot is at the same position of the annotation then there is a problem.

The blue dot would cover the annotation title.  This is why I wish to find a way to adjust the position of the annotation title when the current user position happens to be very close to or at the same location as the map annotation.

Comment: and your question is: `how to change the position?` or `how to change it if its close to the user position?`

Comment: I wish to ask how to change the position of the annotation title.  It being close to the user location blue dot and being covered by it is the reason.  I don't mind if anyone can provide both determining if the annotation title is currently being covered and how to adjust the annotation title position.

Comment: I think the only way is to subclass `MKAnnotationView` or it's subclass `MKPinAnnotationView` and then use its `var centerOffset: CGPoint { get set }` to modify the position

Comment: Many thanks! Will give it a try.

Comment: It seems that centerOffset moves the whole MKAnnotationView image. I wish to move the small pin title display only.